# Running MSBuild from Cruise Control .NET with 64 tools environment enabled

Tags: msbuild, 64-bit, cruisecontrol.net

I was running into the a linker error: Error C1002 compiler is out of heap space in pass 2 (while building using Visual Studio 2015) recently and my solution was to use msbuild from the command line making sure to enable the 64 bit toolset (vcvars64.bat) from the VS2015 x64 Native Tools command prompt.
This fixed the problem, but when creating release builds, I use Cruise Control .NET, I not sure how to do the same thing from that environment.
Has anyone done something similar?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MSBuild property you might want to set is [PreferredToolArchitecture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/msbuild-visual-cpp-overview?view=msvc-170#preferredtoolarchitecture-property).

Answer (score 1):

you can use the msbuild task.

https://ccnet.github.io/CruiseControl.NET/projects/ccnet/wiki/MsBuild_Task.html

that allows to specify all the options.
Another option is to make a batch file that calls msbuild with all the options specified, and call the batch file with the exec task:
https://ccnet.github.io/CruiseControl.NET/projects/ccnet/wiki/Executable_Task.html